# How to get last value inserted with javascript

Tags: jquery

I have got a simple input tag

```
<input type="text" id="textb" name="textbox"/>
```

jquery is

```
$("document").ready(function(){

$("#textb").live("keyup",function(){
alert($(this).val());
//this gives me complete value inserted by user 
})
})
```

the question is that i want to get only the last value inserted by user 
if user enter ("hello"),Than it should show alert("o")

Comment: How do you know it's the "last value inserted"?

Comment: i want to get the last value inserted...??

Comment: Like I said, how would you know what the "last value inserted" is? What will tell you "oh, the user has inserted a 'last value'"? This would be a good starting point to solving your problem.

Comment: you didn't understand what i want to say..if user enters(i am user) Than the output should be (r)....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could update to this:

```
alert($(this).val().substr($(this).val().length-1));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
jQuery("document").ready(function($){
    $("input").bind("keyup",function(e){
        alert(String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
$("#textb").live("keyup",function(){
    alert($(this).val().slice(-1));
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/V3RAF/

or:

```
$("#textb").on("blur",function(){
    alert($(this).val().slice(-1));
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/V3RAF/1/

Comment: Ok, I *must* be reading the OP wrong. If I type in "hello" I still get an alert for each character right?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend putting the output in a div as it is more user friendly.

```
    $( document ).ready( function() {
        $( 'input' ).keyup( function( evt ) {
            var val = $( this ).val(),
            newVal = val.substr( -1, 1 );

            $( '#output' ).empty();
            $( '#output' ).html( newVal );
        });
    });
```

or see the user friendly version here http://jsfiddle.net/wh1t3w0lf21/pUNXD/